# App Store Connect API/fastlane: how to "Developer Reject" submission after review has started

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

The App Store Connect API has an endpoint to delete a submission (to "Developer Reject" it):

`DELETE https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/appStoreVersionSubmissions/{id}`

This endpoint doesn't work once the submission enters review (or has been approved), as noted in the docs:

> Use this endpoint to remove a version from App Review if the review hasn’t yet started. This request fails with an appropriate error if the app is already in review.

I can't seem to find any way to "Developer Reject" *after* review has started - am I missing an endpoint in the ASC API or perhaps some fastlane action that allows you to do this??

Note that you can definitely take this action via the UI:

[image: asc screenshot]

(the "cancel this release" CTA lands you back in a "Developer Rejected" state as expected)

Thanks in advance for any guidance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted and heard back from Apple dev support about this: apparently post-review developer rejection is not currently supported via the API. They said they'll submit this as a feature request to the appropriate team, not sure how that usually goes but

**Update Nov 2021**:

This is now fixed! Docs have been updated accordingly, and you can see a list of the different states in which you *are* able to Developer Reject via the API [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev04f55d711).